# JSON parsing using Volley and show them in ListView Android (Only Text)

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

I just want to get the list of title using volley and display them in listview in android. I have been searching on google for days, I cant get correct reference. Please provide me some good example or reference.

Answer (score 2):

**Google** recommends to write a singleton class

```
 public class MySingleton {
        private static MySingleton mInstance;
        private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
        private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        private static Context mCtx;

        private MySingleton(Context context) {
            mCtx = context;
            mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                    new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
        }

        public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
            }
            return mInstance;
        }

        public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
            if (mRequestQueue == null) {
                // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
                // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
                mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
            }
            return mRequestQueue;
        }

        public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
            getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }

        public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
            return mImageLoader;
        }
    }
```

And then make a request with a queue in your activity and to add this to your list view you can use this approach

```
    List<String> genericList = new LinkedList<String>();
    String url = "http://YOUR-JSON-URL.COM";
    ListView lvStatus = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); // Bind your list view with R.id.YOUR-LISTVIEW-ID

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        try {
            result = response.getString("Name"); // Use this to parse an specific value from your JSON, here i'm getting the field "Name", otherwise use reponse.toString()
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        genericList.add(result); // Add the string to a List
        String[] status = generic.toArray(new String[0]); // Convert your List to an Array
        lvStatus.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, status)); // Set the Array to your adapter and that's it

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

Useful links:

[Google Developers - Making a Standard Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, but it must view the text in listview, I'm not sure about displaying the text in listview. so give me some example please.

Comment: Updated the answer so response can be added to your ListView, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This site helped me a lot. There are good examples:
[androidhive](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Comment: Ya i have Checked them to but I think, they have not given for showing the text in listview